# Uncaught ReferenceError: latLng is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I my google map,i am trying to show the latitude and longitude of the marker position.I am getting the following error `"Uncaught ReferenceError: latLng is not defined "`.What should i include here.

my codes are as follows

js:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346),
        zoom: 2,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function addMarker() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346),
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
}
//show the marker position

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat(),
        latLng.lng()
    ].join(', ');
}
updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
geocodePosition(latLng);
```

html:

```
<div id="info"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your full code in jsfiddle. It is obvious that latLng is not defined for certain reference. We need to know at what position error is occurring.

Comment: You are calling `updateMarkerPosition(latLng);`, but I don't see `latLng` defined anywhere in your code. No wonder you get that error. *"What should i include here"* You have to define `latLng` if you want to use it.

Comment: @specialscope Error is occuring in this line "updateMarkerPosition(latLng);"

Comment: @specialscope please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VqD92/1/

Comment: I added this line "var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346);" but still problem is their

Comment: @Monk: Your fiddle doesn't work because `< meta name = "viewport"
content = "initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" / >` is not valid JavaScript. It throws a syntax error. But event without that, since you are not calling any functions, nothing happens in your fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must have forgotten to initialize your map. I have fixed your fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/Lt2rp/1/

```
  var map;
initialize();
var curlatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346)
updateMarkerPosition(curlatLng);


function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346),
        zoom: 2,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function addMarker() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.3456, 151.4346),
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat(),
        latLng.lng()
    ].join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Your answer is working fine but what i need was if the application is used in Australia,it should defaultly shows the current location in Australia.Here you had hardcoded the values and showing.How to do accomplish that.

Comment: I am using marker also,so the current location is marked by a marker

Comment: Could you please check and tell me how to set that.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that you didn't specify (i.e. define) 'latLng' for "updateMarkerPosition(latLng)" for example, var latLng = "37.780145,-122.418435" (note that you may need to convert this string coordinate to actual numbers later on). There are also a few things to note:

1. the "geocodePosition" function is not defined.
2. the "updateMarkerPosition" function is not quite correct, so even if you pass in lat lng values to this function (e.g. "updateMarkerPosition(-27.3959,153.0626)" it will not be displayed properly. This is because there is no properties "lat" and "lng" for latLng.
3. "updateMarkerPosition" function is not updating or doing anything to the map.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but here's a quick and dirty example, where google map picks up your current location on load and displays your location coordinates. You can then specify the coordinates (in this format: 37.780145,-122.418435) into the text box and hit search. The map will then update and display the position that you entered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      #map-canvas {
        height: 400px;
        width: 500px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

    <script>
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var posRounded = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(4) + "," + position.coords.longitude.toFixed(4);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              content: 'You are here: ' + posRounded
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
      }

      function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
          var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
          var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
          content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
      }

      // Custom Function: Update Marker Position
      function updateMarkerPosition() {
        var latLng = document.getElementsByClassName('lat-lng')[0].value.replace(" ","").split(",");
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[0], latLng[1]);
        var posRounded = parseFloat(latLng[0]).toFixed(4) + "," + parseFloat(latLng[1]).toFixed(4);

        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[0], latLng[1]),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };
        var infowindowOptions = {
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'You are here: ' + posRounded
        };
        var markerOptions = {
          map: map,
          position: pos
        }

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infowindowOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Google Map</h2>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="info" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <input class="lat-lng" type="text" placeholder="Enter lat lng here..."/>
      <button type="button" onclick="updateMarkerPosition()">Look it up!</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ,your answer works fine,but what i want is if i keep a marker in some position,it should say the latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

Just as a sidenote to anyone who stumbles across this question, I found that a plain object with 'lat' and 'lng' properties also tends to work fine if LatLng isn't available for prior to map initialisation.

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}
gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: myLatLng
});
```